# How to catch a unique constraint error for each Index?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a data table with many columns unique indexed. When I update, there may be some columns duplicates. I am using the following way to catch errors

```
 EXCEPTION
     WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX
        THEN OPEN cur FOR SELECT 'DUP' result from dual;
```

But now i want catch exception on each index, like

```
 EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX1
            THEN OPEN cur FOR SELECT 'DUP1' result from dual; 
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX2
            THEN OPEN cur FOR SELECT 'DUP2' result from dual;
```

So how can i do that ?

Comment: Looks like you need to parse error message to understand which constraint was violated

Comment: Why don't you check the uniqueness and then proceed accordingly?  Exception handling should only display error message and terminate, it should never have any form of processing logic.

Comment: Bear in mind that most database systems will only report the *first* constraint violation even if (had it continued processing) multiple constraints *would* have been violated. I don't think Oracle is any different here. So you're still not going to get a "correct" answer using this sort of logic if the data would have violated both `INDEX1` and `INDEX2`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761268/multiple-constraints-in-table-how-to-get-all-violations. Use deferred constraint.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the index_name from `user_constraints` by parsing the error message `SQLERRM`

```
WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX 
THEN
v_errm := SQLERRM;
SELECT INDEX_NAME into v_INDEX_NAME 
FROM user_constraints WHERE INDEX_OWNER||'.'||constraint_name = 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_errm,'unique constraint +\((.+)\) +violated',1,1,'i',1);

CASE  v_INDEX_NAME 
     WHEN 'INDEX1' THEN OPEN cur FOR SELECT 'DUP1' result from dual; 
     WHEN 'INDEX2' THEN OPEN cur FOR SELECT 'DUP2' result from dual;
     ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END CASE;
```

Do note that you may also have to handle `NO_DATA_FOUND` by putting the select statement inside another `BEGIN..EXCEPTION..END` or using other methods. But, this would not be required if your `user_constraints` has the correct details of the raised constraint.