# How to capture constraint name using save exception in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to perform delete in bulk from multiple tables.
These tables are having referential integrity constraint enabled.
In case if I miss out to delete any record from child table, I should be able to capture the foreign key constraint name that got violated.

I'm able to capture the foreign key constraint name if I don't use SAVE EXCEPTIONS, however if I use SAVE EXCEPTIONS I'm not able to capture the name.

e.g. To demonstrate I have created 2 tables with referential integrity.

```
test_parent(id number,PARENT_NAME  VARCHAR2)
test_child (id number,child_NAME  VARCHAR2)
```

id column is referenced from test_child to test_parent

I inserted few records in both and then tried to delete from test_parent without deleting from `test_child` to replicate the error for demonstration.

```
set serveroutput on <br>
declare <br>
cursor cp is select * from test_parent;<br>
type t_cp is table of cp%rowtype;<br>
tt_cp t_cp;<br>
begin<br>
select * bulk collect into tt_cp from test_parent;<br>
begin<br>
forall idx in 1..tt_cp.count save exceptions<br>
delete from TEST_PARENT where id=tt_cp(idx).id;<br>
exception<br>
when others then<br>
for i in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count<br>
loop<br>
  dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm(-1 * SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));<br>
end loop;<br>
end;<br>
exception<br>
when others then<br>
rollback;<br>
dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);<br>
rollback;<br>
end;<br>
/<br>
```

How do I capture the constraint name along with using `SAVE EXCEPTIONS`?

[Below output if I don't use SAVE EXCEPTIONS]

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint **(SYSTEM.SYS_C0014790)** violated - child record found

[Below output if I use SAVE EXCEPTIONS]

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (.) violated - child record found
>   ORA-02292: integrity constraint (.) violated - child record found

Comment: You must be looking for [DML Error Logging](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2)

Comment: Take a look at this thread on AskTom - it's the same question, and Tom gives a good way to solve it.  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532075500346668221   Note that - since `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS` stores only error codes, not error messages (and therefore the constraint name is simply not captured), you will not be able to solve your problem with `SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS` alone.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761268/multiple-constraints-in-table-how-to-get-all-violations